# iOS:Masonry+UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, masonry

I am attempting to use `[UIView animationWithDuration]` method to animate the UIView with the constraints.

I am quite familiar with animation using UIView.frame which is quite straight forward.

in the init method I add those subviews

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self addSubview:self.bg_view];
        [self.bg_view addSubview:self.content];
        [self.bg_view addSubview:self.titleView];
        [self.bg_view addSubview:self.reward];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And as the document shown on the Masonry, the constraints are set in the

```
-(void)updateConstraints
{
    [self makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo([UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow);
    }];

    [self.bg_view makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self);
    }];

    [self.titleView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.bg_view.centerX);
        make.top.equalTo(self.bg_view.top).with.offset(150);
    }];

    [self.content makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(self.bg_view).with.offset(-k_Margin*2);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.reward.top).with.offset(-20);
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.bg_view);
        make.top.equalTo(self.titleView.bottom).with.offset(20);
    }];

    [self.reward makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.bg_view.centerX);
        make.top.equalTo(self.content.bottom).with.offset(20);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.bg_view.bottom).with.offset(-40);
    }];

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

And in the show method

```
-(void)show
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self];
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        /* I have tried variety ways to get the uiview come into the 
screen from the top*/
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted some code below to help you achieve this, I used a viewcontroller, you can use a UIView like they do in the Masonry examples if you want to. I placed a button on my view and hooked it up to my 'show' method.

Have a look at the iOS examples in the Masonry project, they are quite helpful.

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) UIView *subView;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat topValue;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.subView];
    self.topValue = -128;
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [self.subView mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(@(self.topValue));
        make.width.equalTo(@128);
        make.height.equalTo(@128);
        make.leading.equalTo(@0);
    }];

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}

- (IBAction)show:(id)sender {
    self.topValue = (self.topValue == 0) ? -128 : 0;

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Sure, it's the answer. But I need to call [UIView layoutIfNeeded] before changing the constraint value to apply the start position of the animation.

Comment: Cool, however I don't think that's the case, updateViewContraints is called during the view lifecycle and since the initial value of 'topValue' is set it should start in the correct place, did you need to explicitly call it to get it to work?